# How to get malformed or string type data from a numeric column in hive?

Tags: hive

I have a column id (data type integer) containing the following records:

```
1
2
NULL
x
y
```

As hive automatically converts `x` and `y` into NULL, I'm first casting the id column to a string. Now I want `count(id)` where id is not from [0-9] and also not NULL. In my case, the count should be 2, but it is not working with `x`and `y`. I am also getting count of NULL's, in my example 3.

I have tried using `LIKE`, `RLIKE` and also with `regexp_extract(id,'\&q=([^\&]+)`.

Can some one suggest me how to achieve this?

Comment: Why not just subtract `1` from the `count` ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried something similar and it is working for me. I created an external table with your data:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE temp_count (count STRING)  ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LOCATION 'user/$username/data'
```

Now I am running a query like this: 
(Edited)

```
select count(*) from (select (count - count) as value from temp_count where count != 'NULL')q1 where value is NULL;
```

and I am getting 2 as the output.

Let me know if I am missing something here

Comment: I have tried your solution but in this way I'll be able to get the count of all integer values present in column not the the count of malformed data.

Comment: oh my bad, I misinterpreted the question...will check that and get back to you

Comment: Edited the answer, please check now